# EXTjs: how to read rss feed from ashx page to a store ?

Tags: xml, extjs, rss, store, ashx

I want to get the rss feed of an ashx page to an EXTjs store. It works perfectly with a xml page. but when I test it on an ashx page it doesn't !!!

link: http://met.guc.edu.eg/Feeds/Course.ashx?c=240

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://met.guc.edu.eg/Feeds/Course.ashx?c=240',
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                record: 'item',
            }
        },
        fields: ['title','category','pubDateParsed'],
        groupField: 'category',
        sorters: [{property: 'pubDateParsed', direction: 'DESC'}]
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your issue is likely that the browser is preventing you from fetching the feed because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).**

With a traditional AJAX call you can only communicate with the site that your page is hosted on (unless you adjust your settings to allow it).

You will either need to setup a proxy page on your site that will fetch and echo the data, or run it through something like [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to [convert the XML into JSON](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/yahoo-pipes-xml-json) and use a dynamic script tag, which does not have the same origin policy restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some filter, that prevent access.

So, I can `ping` met.guc.edu.eg. `nslookup` said that met.guc.edu.eg has ip: `62.241.151.180`... but `http:/62.241.151.180/Feeds/Course.ashx?c=240` returns 404.

I even cann't connect to it via telnet to get response without browser.

When I try it from ExtJS code I get [Error 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have the proxy as:

```
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: 'http://met.guc.edu.eg/Feeds/Course.ashx?c=240',
reader: {
     type: 'xml',
     root: 'channel',
     record: 'item'
}
```