# Populate list from external ajax url in sencha

Tags: ajax, url, extjs, model, store

I'm using Sencha 2.2.0 and i`m trying to populate a list component from a XML which came from a RSS url.
Example: http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/NoticiasHome/rss.aspx?idioma=pt-br&ano=2012

So, i created the view News.js:

```
Ext.define('Investidor.view.News', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'news',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.reader.Xml',
        'Ext.dataview.List'
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'Notícias',
        iconCls: 'star',

        items: {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            store: 'News'
        }
    }
});
```

Which uses the store News.js:

```
Ext.define('Investidor.store.News', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'Investidor.model.NewsItem',

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/NoticiasHome/rss.aspx?idioma=pt-br&ano=2012',
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                record: 'item',
                rootProperty: 'channel'
...
```

Which uses the model NewsItem.js:

```
Ext.define('Investidor.model.NewsItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: ['title', 'description', 'link', 'pubDate']
    }
});
```

The thing is: The page come in blank, and i don't see the browser trying to do an GET request (i'm seeing on chrome develop tool). So i think that the sencha touch isn`t consuming the URL. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXTjs: how to read rss feed from ashx page to a store ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135965/extjs-how-to-read-rss-feed-from-ashx-page-to-a-store)